# How to make POST call using HttpURLConnection with JSON data in Android

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

please help me out with this problem.
I want to make a POST call with JSON data that should appear in body to request but i am not able to do that. I made POST call and getting data but data is not in JSON format.

Code :

```
data = "{'mobile':'"+mobile_number+"','password':'"+mypassword+"'}";
byte[] dataPost = data.getBytes();
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
//urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF8");
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(dataPost);
os.close();
```

Result is coming like below

```
body:
    {'a':'b','c':'d'}:""
```

Please Help me. i am new to android Development.

Thanks

Comment: Revise your question. It's not exactly clear what you're asking. It looks like you're saying that your JSON post does not match what you're receiving on the server side.

Comment: ya.. You are right. can you give me the correct code for this.